# "Invalid Expression Term 'sbyte'"

Tags: c#, variables

I'm getting the Error `Invalid Expression Term 'sbyte'`.

I'm very new to code and not entirely sure what I've done wrong. I'm getting the error after changing the variable from `String` because numbers are to be typed into the line and then used later on in the code.

Why am I getting the error?

---

```
String Name = "";
String Team1 = "";
String Team2 = "";
String Team3 = "";
String Team4 = "";
sbyte Score1 = 0;
sbyte Score2 = 0;
sbyte Score3 = 0;
sbyte Score4 = 0;
String Winner1 = "";
String Winner2 = "";

Console.WriteLine("What's your name?");
Name = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Hello " + Name + ", enter the names of the 4 teams you want to see play below.");
Team1 = Console.ReadLine();
Team2 = Console.ReadLine();
Team3 = Console.ReadLine();
Team4 = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Ok, Here are todays matches");
Console.WriteLine("___________________________");
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine(Team1 + " vs " + Team2);
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine(Team3 + " vs " + Team4);
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("___________________________");
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("How many goals did " + Team1 + " Score?");
Score1 = sbyte (Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("How many goals did " + Team2 + " Score?");
Score2 = sbyte (Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("How many goals did " + Team3 + " Score?");
Score3 = sbyte (Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("How many goals did " + Team4 + " Score?");
Score4 = sbyte (Console.ReadLine());
```

Comment: Score1 = sbyte.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Answer (score 3):

The problem is here:

```
Score1 = sbyte (Console.ReadLine());
```

Console.ReadLine() returns a string.  You need to convert that to a signed byte.  The code you've written to do that is incorrect and therefore does not compile.

You could use the method SByte.Parse or the more robust SByte.TryParse to achieve this.  The code you've written looks like an attempt to cast directly, which would properly be written

```
Score1 = (sbyte)Console.ReadLine();
```

This will fail at run-time, though, because it is not possible to cast a string directly to a numeric type.

You would also do well to read up on naming conventions.  Local variables typically start with lower-case letters, like this:

```
String name = "";
String team1 = "";
sbyte score1 = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be trying to use casting to convert a string to its sbyte representation. That won't work. (It almost appears that you are trying C++ syntax for constructing a type, that doesn't work either).

Instead, look at Byte.Parse() (or SByte equivalent):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k0s9b1y3(v=vs.110).aspx

```
string s = Console.ReadLine();
sbyte b = SByte.Parse(s);
Console.WriteLine("sbyte '{0}'", b);
```

Parse will throw an exception if the format is incorrect, so use a try/catch block. Otherwise, TryParse() will not throw an exception, and you just check the return value.

More samples here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xbtzcc4w(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your variable in three ways.

```
//Method 1
sbyte one = sbyte.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

//method two
sbyte two = null;
sbyte.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),two);

//method three
sbyte three = Convert.ToSByte(Console.ReadLine());
```

Any of the three will work for you.